# Finding the count of characters and numbers in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a table test as below

```
NAME
---------
abc1234
XYZ12789
a12X8b78Y9c5Z
```

I try to find out the count of number of numbers and characters in the string as

```
select name,length(replace(translate(lower(name),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',' '),'      ','')) as num_count,
length(replace(translate(name,'1234567890',' '),' ','')) as char_count
from test6;
```

Its executing fine giving the output

```
NAME    NUM_COUNT   CHAR_COUNT
abc1234         4       3
XYZ12789        5       3
a12X8b78Y9c5Z   7       6
```

But my question is there any option by not giving the `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
and `1234567890` manually

Comment: What database engine are you using? There is no standard SQL function that would help with this, but some database management systems do have proprietary functions that might do the trick.

Comment: The values for `CHAR_COUNT` and `NUM_COUNT` are inverted on your sample output.

Comment: i am using Oracle PL/SQL in which to my knowledge there is no function which would directly give the count of number of characters or numbers in a string .
If any operation can be done other than giving manually let me know..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are using Oracle PLSQL, and as far as I know, there isn't any "built-in" method (in PLSQL) that counts the number of digits/characters in a string.

But, you can do the following to count characters:
`select LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd12345','[0-9]')) from dual`

and digits:
`select LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd12345','[a-zA-Z]')) from dual`

Or, in your case:

```
select name,
LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[a-zA-Z]','')) as num_count,
LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[0-9]','')) as char_count,
from test6;
```

**For Bill the Lizard:**
My answer was tested on Oracle 11g and it works just fine!
If you decide to delete my answer again, please be kind enough to add a comment that explains why. I was also looking for you in the chat rooms...

Comment: @Aspirant - it says that Bill the Lizard deleted it, not you. And you're most welcome!

Answer (score 10):

@alfasin answer is good, but if you're using 11g then it can get simpler:

```
select name,
REGEXP_count(name,'\d') as num_count,
REGEXP_count(name,'[a-zA-Z]') as char_count,
from test6;
```

Comment: nice! or use regexp_count(name, '[[:alpha:]]') and regexp_count(name, '[[:digit:]]'), or for both regexp_count(name, '[[:alnum:]]')