# Extracting alpha and numeric parts from a column

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, alphanumeric

I have a table `tab1` with a column `col1` that has compound alpha-then-numeric values, like this:

```
abc123
xy45
def6
z9
```

I need to extract the values as separate columns in a query, with the numeric part in a column of integer datatype.

If the two values had a consistent start and end positions, the job could be done with `substring()`, as you can see the start of the numeric part varies.

Is there an elegant way to tackle this, or must it be done with a series of unions of each possible start point using a regex match to separate the cases, or rolled up in a huge case statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?939700-How-do-I-Split-an-alphanumeric-string-into-array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing numbers from string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855053/removing-numbers-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: @mrcoder I seek an SQL-only solution. Your links are for application code solutions

Comment: See the answer I wrote [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11380726/1057429) - just remove the `LENGTH` part and you'll get what you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
SELECT
  @col:=col1 AS col, 
  @num:=REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(@col) AS UNSIGNED)) AS num,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(@col, @num, 1) AS word
FROM
  tab1
```

-will work only if your column contain letters and then numbers (like you've described). That's why double [`REVERSE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) is needed (otherwise `CAST()` will have no effect). Check this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c583b/20).

Comment: +1ed but just noticed extra care needs to be taken for strings ending in `0`, could append a `1` to the end of each value and then trim it after the `CAST`.

Comment: Yep, it's a bit 'bully' solution - also need to care about data type length since string can hold anything while integer/float are limited