# MySQL Fulltext separate digits and letters?

Tags: mysql, plugins, full-text-search

Lets say we have 'ABCD1234EF' word in text. Now to find it, I have to match exact word. The goal is to find it by 'ABCD1234EF', 'ABCD', '1234' or 'EF' strings. NOT by 'CD12' or anything like it. Parameter 'ft_min_word_len' is  set to 1.

It's only option to create second column and store splited values there? Could it be done by MySQL?

I have found something on MySQL site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-text-plugins.html. But it brings more questions than it solves.

- does it replace original mysql parser?
- how to compile it on Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest route would be splitting your input string into three separate columns with SQL (based on [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20899123/1446005) perhaps,).

Writting your own fulltext plugin essentially moves this logic to a lower with uncertain added value ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/writing-full-text-plugins.html)):

> The main parsing function, `simple_parser_parse()`, acts as a replacement for the built-in full-text parser, so it needs to split text into words and pass each word to the server.

This also answers your first bullet question: this procedure replaces the *full-text parser* (not the SQL parser, if this was your question).

The [MySQL compilation instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/installing-source-distribution.html) provide Windows-specific steps.

Comment: Indeed pure SQL approach would be ideal. But I have actually two columns I need to index. With multiple words, values with digits on all possible places. No rule applicable. Now I try to compile the plugin without a proper tool. Still learning. SQL trigger-like solution is still prefered. Any other non-SQL solution will work for sure too, but I'm trying to avoid it, because it will need a lot of changes in my app.