# SQL Query to identify repeated digits in a number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am stuck at identifying repeated digits in a number and its count.

The query, for example, should be able to identify

```
DataColumn ----------- Result1(repeated digit)---------------Result 2 (count of repeated digit)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
11112---------------------1--------------------------------------------4
222AA---------------------2--------------------------------------------3
0011---------------------0,1-------------------------------------------2,2
1111 ---------------------1--------------------------------------------4
```

Kindly guide

Comment: Repeated consecutively? So what is the result: `121212`?Is it an `int` column?

Comment: So, here is the example you are looking for, try working on [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380329/finding-the-count-of-characters-and-numbers-in-a-string

Comment: please show some code examples not just oytput.

Answer (score 3):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98fc1/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create function [dbo].[CountRepeatedDigits]
(
  @Data varchar(10)
)
returns @returntable table 
(
  Result1 varchar(10),
  Result2 varchar(10)
)
as
begin
  declare @Result1 varchar(10) = ''
  declare @Result2 varchar(10) = ''
  declare @C1 varchar(1) = ''
  declare @C2 varchar(1) = ''
  declare @I int = 1
  declare @D varchar(11) = @Data + 'X'

  while len(@D) > 0
  begin
    set @C1 = left(@D, 1)

    if patindex('[0-9]', @C1) > 0 and
       patindex('[0-9]', @C2) > 0 and
       @C1 = @C2
    begin
      set @I += 1
    end
    else
    begin
      if @I > 1
      begin
        set @Result1 += ','
        set @Result1 += @C2

        set @Result2 += ','
        set @Result2 += cast(@I as varchar(11))
      end
      set @I = 1
    end

    set @C2 = @C1
    set @D = stuff(@D, 1, 1, '')
  end

  insert @returntable(Result1, Result2)
  select stuff(@Result1, 1, 1, ''), stuff(@Result2, 1, 1, '')

  return 
end

go

create table YourTable(DataColumn varchar(10))

insert into YourTable values 
('11112'),
('222AA'),
('0011'),
('1111'),
('1122334455')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select DataColumn,
       C.Result1,
       C.Result2
from YourTable as T
  cross apply dbo.CountRepeatedDigits(T.DataColumn) as C
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98fc1/1/0)**:

```
| DATACOLUMN |   RESULT1 |   RESULT2 |
|------------|-----------|-----------|
|      11112 |         1 |         4 |
|      222AA |         2 |         3 |
|       0011 |       0,1 |       2,2 |
|       1111 |         1 |         4 |
| 1122334455 | 1,2,3,4,5 | 2,2,2,2,2 |
```

Answer (score -1):

Try query like this:

```
select length('1112') - length(regexp_replace('11112', '(1,2)', '')) from dual;
```

Comment: How does this answer the users question ? Explain your answer