# how to find the number of characters in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to find the number of characters in mysql

for e.g

```
Student_Name
-------------
John
```

contain the four characters in field,

Need to find out this with the help of query

Comment: [Finding the count of characters and numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380329/finding-the-count-of-characters-and-numbers-in-a-string)

Comment: Thanks Jixone and Thomas, "length" function is working very well

Comment: It's usually charlength

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: LEN is not supporting in mysql

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-length-function.php

follow this url

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(Student_Name) FROM Table_Name
```

you can use WHERE clause with this as well:

```
SELECT Student_Name, CHAR_LENGTH(Student_Name)  AS 'char length' FROM Table_Name WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(Student_Name)>3;
```

View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734334/mysql-length-vs-char-length) for difference between Length and char_length.

Hope it will help!!

Comment: You are welcome @Sdesh

Answer (score -1):

The `LEN()` function returns the length of the value in a text field in `mysql`.

```
SELECT LEN(here the column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Here is a link for detail explanation https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

Comment: LEN() not supporting in mysql