# Using MYSQL to delete rows with certain amount of numbers in a string

Tags: mysql

is there a way to delete from a table an email address that has a certain amount of numbers in a string. For example, g1az11@hotmail.com would be fine as it has 3 numbers in there but g1az111@hotmail.com would be removed since there are 4numbers in the string.

I need this to be done in a pure MySql query I am not able to run through these through PHP first.

Comment: this is a super odd request - you could probably use a regex search query to find the entries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the count of characters and numbers in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380329/finding-the-count-of-characters-and-numbers-in-a-string)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Comment: no that link is for `òracle`,but not for `mysql` @pmaldera